# Marketing Cloud - Adding additional Primary Keys to a Existing Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud

Should it be possible to update an existing data extension to add additional primary keys?

We have a current Data Extension that has a primary key as subscriber key however noticed that a person can be in the data more than once but unique based on store ID so wanted to update the data extension to add a second primary key on store location. I could have sworn i was able to do this in the past.

Is this a permission issue or is it not possible once the data extension has been created?

I can see if i add an additional field, i can add that as the primary key, just wont let me update an exciting field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the DE has data in it you cannot add a primary key. Once you clear the data you can delete the field you want to add the primary key, then re-add it and select it as a primarykey. You could also copy the DE and then set the  primary key then use a query activity to populate the new DE if you need to save the data

Comment: Thanks, i cleared out the data however still wont let me add a primary key. Was trying to do it without creating a new DE as its used to populate a journey. Not a biggie just hoping it was permission issue

Comment: To add on, see this question for more info on copying de to edit pkeys: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/265485/changing-the-pk-column-of-a-data-extension-without-completely-recreating-it

Comment: @Andyw I updated the steps to edit, you have to remove the field and re-add it